# Sorting an object of an object by value in typescritpt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, sorting, object

I have an object that contains object and need to sort it by count

```
var obj={
  "error1":{
    "count":45,
    "ids":['123','352']
  },
  "error2":{
    "count":3,
    "ids":['13','2']
  },
  "error3":{
    "count":15,
    "ids":['42','7']
  }
}
```

I want to sort by count that the result would be

```
var obj={
   "error2":{
    "count":3,
    "ids":['13','2']
  },
   "error3":{
    "count":15,
    "ids":['42','7']
  },
  "error1":{
    "count":45,
    "ids":['123','352']
  }
}
```

How can I do that

Comment: Tread carefully here. This is possible in most implementations but and is in the language spec but *in general* in programming associative data structures are not ordered. Why do you need this?

Comment: check this response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value